# Operating Systems development for MIPS

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, mips

Lately, I have been reading about operating systems a lot. It is also one of my official courses the present semester, along with computer architecture, in which we are studying the MIPS architecture.

I was wondering if it would be a good idea to write a basic OS for MIPS. I have studied the x86 assembly and architecture, and it appears to be a lot more complicated than MIPS. Especially, the assembly for MIPS, being RISC, appears to be a lot easier. (I may be entirely wrong about my assumptions, and would be glad if someone corrected me on them).

Can someone suggest me good resources for OS development in MIPS? Most of the online resources are relevant to the Intel architecture. And also, any generic advice on operating systems development would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: MIPS being RISC doesn't make it easier to write "code in general", it just has irrelevant consequences such as having to do explicit loads and stores all the time (no aluop with memory operand), needing a LI pseudoinstruction instead of allowing it to be an actual instruction, etc. The parts of x86 relevant for OSdev are complicated because of the build-up of cruft, not CISC-ness.

Comment: Can you suggest some resources?

Comment: x86 is pretty much the last instruction set you would want to learn, ugly to start and then loaded with decades of baggage.  mips is a lot cleaner, there are others.   But as far as operating system development goes, certainly a basic one, it is pretty much irrelevant.  mips will be easier for the assembly parts, but the rest should be in C or something else so target doesnt matter.